# How do you import a CSV line-by-line in Netlogo?

Tags: string, list, netlogo

How do I import data from a CSV file and convert it line-by-line so I can use it in my program? I want it to be a string but I keep getting error messages that it is still a list or a list of lists.

I am trying to copy the example given in the Netlogo User Manual for reading a file one line per tick (see below). I created a simple example.

```
extensions [CSV]
globals [date]


to setup
  clear-all
  file-close-all
  file-open "S&PDate.csv"
  set date current-date
  reset-ticks
end

to go
   if file-at-end? [stop]
   set date current-date
   tick
end

to-report current-date 
   file-open "S&PDate.csv"
   let result csv:from-row file-read-line 
   while [ not file-at-end? ] [
   let row csv:from-row file-read-line
   set result (map result row)
     ]
   file-close
   report result
end
```

[From NetLogo User Manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhQIl.png)

Comment: Why "line-by-line"?  Is that a requirement?  Unless it is a huge file, just read the whole file at one go, using `csv:from-file`.  You can then fetch any item of the result whenever you wish.  (Separately: your use of `map` is incorrect.)

Comment: Why do you want the result to be a string? CSV is a format for storing lists of lists. If you just want the raw string contents of the file, you can use the built-in `file-` primitives in NetLogo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My idea is to import the CSV data all at once as a list, then extract the value from the list by the number of ticks (i.e. line-by-line).

```
extensions [csv]
globals [data variable]

to setup
file-close-all 
file-open "S&PDate.csv"
;; read the data all at once by using csv:from-file
set data csv:from-file "S&PDate.csv"
reset-ticks
end

to go
if file-at-end? [stop]
;;extract value from the list, using item 0 to remove the list, and just keep the value
set variable item 0 item ticks data
tick  
if ticks = length data [stop]
show variable
end
```

Hope it helps. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Could you provide some extra commentary on this code snippet? @yuJiang?

Comment: Hi Stuart. Sorry, I added some comments and description. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Great stuff @yuJiang. Thanks for making StackoverFlow a better place.

Comment: @maxNeumeyer could you accept this as the accept answer?

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks--still figuring all this out.